# D3.js v4 force layout with link forces causes strange movement when using drag behavior

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I'm trying to create a force layout with d3.js v4 and the mayor part is working really well accept for one problem when using the drag behavior.

When clicking on a node to drag it around the other nodes, which are not connected to the clicked node, fly away:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
width = +svg.attr("width"),
height = +svg.attr("height");

function drawNode(nodes) {
    return svg.selectAll("circle.node")
      .data(nodes, function (d, i) { return d.Id; })
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", "blue")
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));
}

function drawMainNode(nodes) {
    return svg.selectAll("circle.mainnode")
      .data(nodes, function (d, i) { return d.Id; })
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "mainnode")
      .attr("r", 15)
      .attr("fill", "red")
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));
}

function drawLinks(links) {
    return svg.selectAll("line")
      .data(links, function (d, i) { return d.source + "-" + d.target; })
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", 3);
}

function dragstarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) dragSimualtion.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) dragSimualtion.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
}

function ticked() {
    dLinks
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    dNodes
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

    dMainNodes
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}

var dLinks = drawLinks(mainLinks.concat(nodeLinks));
var dNodes = drawNode(nodes);
var dMainNodes = drawMainNode(mainNodes);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(mainNodes.concat(nodes))
                .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
                .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
                .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(20).radius(20))
                .force("links", d3.forceLink(mainLinks.concat(nodeLinks))
                    .id(function (d) { return d.Id; }))
                .alpha(0.9)
                .alphaDecay(0.1)
                .on("tick", ticked);

var dragSimualtion = d3.forceSimulation(mainNodes.concat(nodes))
                .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(20).radius(20))
                .force("links", d3.forceLink(mainLinks.concat(nodeLinks))
                    .id(function (d) { return d.Id; }))
                .alphaDecay(0.1)
                .on("tick", ticked)
                .stop()
```

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/stLCnkoxAGBSkFdKI8kz?p=preview)

I tried using a seperate simulation for the drag event which only uses the link force and collision force - because the nodes should be dragged around with every node attached to them and other non-attached nodes should be pushed away, but only if they collide.

So the question is, how can i prevent the other nodes from flying around?

**Edit1:** My first attempt was using only the first simulation object, but i thought the observed effect was caused by the `d3.forceManyBody` due to its repulsion force. I tried to limit this effect with `distanceMax` but had no success. My second attempt was to use a seperate `d3.forceSimulation` which does only contain the forces relevant for the drag animation.

Comment: It might be because of combination of `d3.forceManyBody` and `d3.forceCollide`. And I dont really think you need the separate simulation for drag event. Just update the default one. See https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2675ff61ea5e063ede2b5d63c08020c7

Comment: My first attempt was to use only one simulation, but i thought the drifting effect of the nodes is caused by the ManyBody force (due to repulsion), so i created the second simulation. I also tried to use disctanceMax() of d3.forceManyBody to limit the repulsion force to a certain range.

Answer (score 0):

the forceCollide of the drag function appears to be the problem...

try:

```
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(20).radius(20).strength(0))
```

then you get the opposite problem, then try between 0 and 1, find one you like.